# Django view request has no user

Tags: django, django-views, django-rest-auth

I am using Django-rest-auth to do authentication. On client side I can get user details of the logged in user like following:

```
 $scope.getUser = function(){

  $http.get("https://localhost:8000/rest-auth/user/").then(function(response){

  $scope.userData = response.data;
  $scope.username = $scope.userData.username;

  console.log(response.data);

});

}
```

However on server side view my request doesn't give me any user details. My views.py looks something like following:

```
#view to call a stored proc that returns an exercise list for a particular user 

def get_exercise_state_by_user_id(request):

print(request.user) # this gives me AnonymousUser 
print(request.user.id) # this gives me None 

results = Exercise_state_ui_model.fetch_exercises(request.user.id, -1)

serializer = ExerciseStateSerializer(results, many=True)
return JSONResponse(serializer.data)
```

As 'request' isn't giving me any user related information following line doesn't do anything.

```
results = Exercise_state_ui_model.fetch_exercises(request.user.id, -1)
```

What could be the problem? Why request do not contain any user related information? What is the workaround?

My settings.py has following:

```
# Application definition
INSTALLED_APPS = (
  'django.contrib.admin',
  'django.contrib.auth',
  'django.contrib.contenttypes',
  'django.contrib.sessions',
  'django.contrib.messages',
  'django.contrib.staticfiles',
  'django.contrib.sites',
  'rest_framework',

  #following was added to allow cross domain requests
  'corsheaders',

  #following were added for ssl thing
  'djangosecure',
  'sslserver',

  #following were added for authentication
  'rest_framework.authtoken',
  'rest_auth',
  'allauth',
  'allauth.account',
  'rest_auth.registration',
  'demo',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
  'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
  'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
  'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
  'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
  'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
  'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
  'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
  'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
  'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
  'djangosecure.middleware.SecurityMiddleware',
  'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
)

REST_SESSION_LOGIN = True
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'
SITE_ID = 1
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED = False
ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATION_METHOD = 'username'
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION = 'optional'

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
    'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
    'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication'
),
}
```

**UPDATE** My loginCtrl looks like following:

```
//Login controller
.controller('loginCtrl', function($scope, $location, $state, djangoAuth, $ionicHistory){

$scope.model = {'username':'','password':''};
$scope.complete = false;
$scope.login = function(formData){
  $scope.errors = [];

    djangoAuth.login($scope.model.username, $scope.model.password)
    .then(function(data){
      // success case
      console.log("Logged in"); 

      //To disable back state 
      $ionicHistory.nextViewOptions({
         disableBack: true
      });
      //On successful login goto start page 
      $state.go('start');

    },function(data){
      // error case
      $scope.errors = data;
    }); 
 }
})
```

Comment: How are you logging the user in?

Comment: I am using django-angular-rest-auth to handle authentication from client side. https://github.com/Tivix/angular-django-registration-auth
This includes a service called 'djangoAuth'

Comment: But are you actually calling the login methods? Your code clearly shows you have an anonymous - ie unauthenticated - user.

Comment: I updated my question with my login controller

Comment: The getUser() method as shown in first code snippet gives me user's username back successfully.